# Eclipse EGit plugin - Submodule compare with HEAD revision shows blank HEAD file

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm having Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 ( 4.4.2 ) with EGit version 4.2

I've java maven project with single submodule. In case I change any of the files in submodule and do compare with HEAD revision , later always shows blank.

Also modified file status icon doesn't show on any of the submodule files

Above 2 scenarios works perfectly fine with non submodule directory.

Please let me know if I'm missing some setting wrt submodule and EGit.

Did google ( and bing as well ) but couldn't find any solution yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To put it mildely, submodules are not the best thing in git.
To organize your repository with folders and/or branches is a way simpler thing to do.

A submodule is in almost every aspect of the parrent repository a different thing. Commits to a submodule are best managed in the repository it points to.
A submodule is in the parrent repository "only" a link to another repositorys commit. So a git status shows only changes to this link and not the changes in the other repository.

If you realy want to use submodules, the best way to work with them is that you checkout the repository of the submodule, make change,commit to it and push to an origin. Then in the parrent Repository in which you want to combine several "children"-repositories for an better overview you update the submodules. With this you change the link to the submodule and have commits in the parrent repository. This ist the only sane way of using submodules in git, I can think of.

Comment: Wolfgang , we are trying to follow BDD approach where features files are in one git repo and it'll be used by different other project repos like iOS , Android , Web etc.  How can I make sure with your approach individual  features folders are in sync with parent one ?